# Styling using id on html form not effective

Tags: html, css, class, responsive-design, styling

Any idea why the styling is not effective when I use id on the form tag but it becomes effective after replacing id with class

```
    <form id="contact-form">
            <label>Subject</label>
            <input class="input-field" type="text" name="subject">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="input-field" type="text" name="email">
            <label>Message</label>
            <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

 

    #contact-form{
display: block
}
```

Comment: do you have another element with that(contact-form) id into page?

Comment: **It's the only tag with that specific id**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is applying to `form` and it is displaying as `block` but it seems you want `form` `child elements` to be displayed `block` so use `*` with `#contact-form`

```css
#contact-form * {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<form id="contact-form">
  <label>Subject</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="text" name="subject">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="text" name="email">
  <label>Message</label>
  <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And `form` tag is a `block-level` element but `input` `label` is not.
You can see by applying other properties to `id`

```css
#contact-form {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="contact-form">
  <label>Subject</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="text" name="subject">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="text" name="email">
  <label>Message</label>
  <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Well, it now works but the styling is not similar (to the one with class="contact-form")

Comment: How it is not similar to ` class="contact-form"` @JumbaMark

Comment: If it helped your issue you can mark answer as accepted @JumbaMark . And if you have any query feel free to comment